# is it possible to declare and return more than one column in a mysql function?

Tags: mysql, function

In addition to 'price', i would like to declare and return a second column named 'tax', but i don't know how to go about it in the right way.

Here's an example of what i'm trying to achieve,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION calcProfit(cost FLOAT, price FLOAT) RETURNS DECIMAL(9,2)
BEGIN
  DECLARE profit DECIMAL(9,2);
  DECLARE tax DECIMAL(9,2);

  SET profit = price-cost;
  SET tax = cost*1.2;

  RETURN profit,tax;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: A function can only return one value. How would you use multiple values when you call the function in an expression? Maybe what you want is a stored procedure instead of the function.

Comment: You could return a JSON or other kind of delimited string, which you then parse into a second function for later use.

Answer (score 2):

Stored routines are of two kinds, 'procedures' and 'functions'; Functions are used to return a value that you can use in an expression for example:
          SELECT sayHello('Frank');  SELECT countName('Frank');

A store procedure is more appropriate for the task. But you probably want to add more complex statements inside this stored routine .. 
Anyway this will return a row with profit and tax.

```
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE calcProfit(IN cost FLOAT, price FLOAT) 
    BEGIN

      DECLARE profit DECIMAL(9,2);
      DECLARE tax DECIMAL(9,2);

      SET profit = price - cost;
      SET tax = cost * 1.2;

      SELECT  profit, tax;
   END
   //
   DELIMITER ;

   CALL calcProfit(1,2);
```